# one-to-one mapping is not working with 2nd-Level-Cache

Tags: nhibernate, caching, fluent-nhibernate, hibernate-mapping, one-to-one

I have declared the fallowing mapping with NHibernate3:

with FluentNHibernate

```
public class ActivityMap : ClassMap<Activity> {
    public ActivityMap() {
        this.Table("Activity");
        this.Cache.ReadWrite();
        this.Version(x => x.ObjectVersion);
        this.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        // snipp

        this.HasOne(x => x.AppointmentRecurrence).Cascade.Delete();
    }
}

public class AppointmentRecurrenceMap : ClassMap<AppointmentRecurrence> {
    public AppointmentRecurrenceMap() {
        this.Table("AppointmentRecurrence");
        this.Cache.ReadWrite();     
        this.Version(x => x.ObjectVersion);
        this.Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.Foreign("Activity");

        // snipp

        this.HasOne(x => x.Activity).Constrained();
    }
}
```

which is generating the fallowing hbm-mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" lazy="false" name="Prayon.Entities.Activity, Prayon.Entities, Version=1.0.0.867, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="Activity">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <id name="Id" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <!-- snipp -->
    <one-to-one cascade="delete" class="Prayon.Entities.AppointmentRecurrence, Prayon.Entities, Version=1.0.0.867, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" foreign-key="FK_Activity_AppointmentRecurrence" name="AppointmentRecurrence" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>


<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" lazy="false" name="Prayon.Entities.AppointmentRecurrence, Prayon.Entities, Version=1.0.0.867, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" table="AppointmentRecurrence">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <id name="Id" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="foreign">
        <param name="property">Activity</param>
      </generator>
    </id>
    <!-- snipp -->
   <one-to-one class="Prayon.Entities.Activity, Prayon.Entities, Version=1.0.0.867, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" constrained="true" foreign-key="FK_AppointmentRecurrence_Activity" name="Activity" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Now, when i select Activities (with a cachable-select), I see in the NHibernate-Profiler, that NHibernate is getting each Activity correct out of the 2nd-Level-Cache, but it will do for each Activity a select to AppointmentReccurrence. What can I do, that it will take the AppointmentReccurrence also from the cache?
I have tried to set a cache-attribute on the one-to-one relationsship, but it seems not be supported.

Comment: Did you ever determine a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do seem to have a problem with the `Constrained` side of your mapping. According to Ayende's [one-to-one](http://ayende.com/blog/3960/nhibernate-mapping-one-to-one) guide:

> Something else to note is that we must specify this with foreign-key=”none”, because otherwise NHibernate’s Schema Export feature would create two foreign keys for us, which would create a circular reference that wouldn’t allow us to insert anything into the database.

Clearly the FK doesn't *actually* exist in your database, but the misconfiguration could conceivably cause issues with the cache:

The way to specify `foreign-key="none"` in Fluent:

```
this.HasOne(x => x.Activity).Constrained().ForeignKey();
```

Comment: mmhh - this is not working. ForeignKey() is generating a Key on the database. ForeignKey("none") will not - but the entity is already not loaded from the chache :-(

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting `.Fetch.Select()` on the relationship? (Random idea from [here](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=982479)) (Honestly, I usually just declare one to one relationships as many to ones since I've found one to one to have too many quirks.)