# hibernate one-to-one mapping second level cache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, second-level-cache

I have Class A and Class B with one-to-one and many-to-one mapping.

```
   Class A {
   int id
   B b
   }

  Class B {
  A a
  }
```

Class A hbm.xml file:

```
   A.hbm.xml:
  <cache usage="read-write" region="A"/>
  <one-to-one name="b" property-ref="a" cascade="all" />
```

Class B hbm.xml file:
     B.hbm.xml:

```
 <cache usage="read-write" region="B"/>
 <many-to-one name="a"
        class="ClassA"
        column="id"
        outer-join="false"
        not-null="true"/>
```

I have created this queryCache to load A objects. But this never cache B objects. Always hits the database to load Objects B. I have enabled queryCache as well as second level cache as true in hibernate xml file.

```
   Query q = session.createQuery("from A   ").setCacheable(true).setCacheRegion("AQueryCache");
```

To load the B objects into the second level cache, what needs to be modified?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is this a one-to-one or many-to-one (bidirectional) relation? Or are these two unidirectional relations (since in A you use property-ref, I guess it is not)?

Comment: @Flavius Thank you for your reply. This is bidirectional one-to-one and many-to-one relationship. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019108/one-to-one-mapping-is-not-working-with-2nd-level-cache    suggests to use many-to-one instead of one-to-one.

Comment: I am not aware of 'too many quirks', and honestly, I am not an experienced ORM developer, but declaring the relation from each side differently seems obviously wrong.

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/associations.html       As per this website, there is A bidirectional one-to-one association on a foreign key, implements the relation from each side differently.